# How can I output a raw byte array into my XML using XmlWriter?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, xml-serialization

I'm trying to output some raw byte data in some of my XML nodes.

I do not believe the `Base64` output to be suitable for my solution.

My current work is as follows:

To save to the file:

(Member function in the container class Foo)

```
public void save(String file)
{
    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo));
    XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(file, settings);
    serializer.Serialize(writer, this);
}
```

To serialize the class (the class is inherited from IXmlSerializable):

(The data in `Bytes` is the raw data)

```
public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
{
    char[] temp = new char[Bytes.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.Length; i++)
    {
        int n = (int)Bytes[i];
        temp[i] = (char)n;
    }
    writer.WriteRaw(temp, 0, temp.Length);
}
```

I'm certain that after this operation the data in `Bytes` exactly matches the data in temp but after I have serialized the class the raw data in the output file does not seem to match, although some parts look similar. I have also tried playing around with encode settings on the `XmlWriter`, but that frequently ends in exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

"I do not believe the Base64 output to be suitable for my solution." o_O, well... then this is not a programming question, but a philosophical one...

Still, and assuming many things, such as that the array `Bytes` contains the byte data of the a file containing a serialized instance of `Foo` as per your `save()` method, keep in mind that `char` represents a Unicode character and its size is 2-bytes... You are adding more bits when converting the `byte` to a `char`...

Oh encodings, encodings, encodings... That's why there exists a Base64!!!